# How to store data(video/image) to Photos from NSStream

Tags: ios, xcode

I am sending file(Video/audio) from one iOS device to another. On destination receiving the file from stream and storing it into Document directory, from there i am moving the file to photos. In some cases like if the destination has only 500MB and i got the same 500MB file from source. i could store it to document directory later i unable to move it to photos, as the 500MB space was occupied by document directory. Is there any way to directly storing the video from NSStream to photos?

Comment: There is an alternate to this, but I am not sure it will work on such a large file. 
You can directly store it in an object `NSData`, and then directly write it into Photos app, by creating a PHAsset object. This way you will be utilising the space but it will require 500MB of space in memory as the entire content is in memory. Not sure if its a good solution but its an option

Comment: @SahebRoy: Thanks for the reply. For example i said 500MB. Suppose If i have a video of 2.5GB and at the same moment remaining threads also access the memory(RAM). It may lead to memory crash. Is there any way to store the data to Photos directly without temporary storage(like Document directory / Memory...)...

Comment: Basically the way to save a video/photo directly into the Gallery/ Photos is by creating a PHAsset, which can be created by a path of Document directory or from Data itself. Now if you go by data then memory constraint can be a problem, the safest bet is to first write the data and then from there you save it.